# How can I build/install Qt-6 with conan?

Tags: qt, installation, conan

I an trying to install Qt with conan. I am following instructions on

```
https://wiki.qt.io/Using_Conan_for_Qt6#Connecting_to_Conan_remote
```

which says that

```
Login to your Qt Account and click on the "Conan Package Manager" link.
```

However, there is no such link on the page I arrive at.
Where can I get a user name and PW?

Comment: There is a Qt package version in ConanCenter: https://conan.io/center/qt, that can be installed with ``conan install ...``. I think the Qt version from their site is no longer available.

Comment: No use. I guess that conan site still attempty to collect qt from their site.qt/6.4.2: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
qt/6.4.2: Trying with 'conancenter'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt
Downloading conanfile.py
Downloading conan_export.tgz
qt/6.4.2: Downloaded recipe revision 4fc29a98d642b2bd7ef2f65f2f649988
Please log in to "qt" to perform this action. Execute "conan user" command.
Remote 'qt' username:

Comment: Maybe ``conan user --clean`` and then ``conan remote list`` should only list the conancenter https://center.conan.io one, not the qt remote.

Comment: I guess something crashed on in connecting Qt site. I can log in from their home page, but  "conan user" etc fails.

Comment: Conan package manager support has ended in December 2022. https://www.qt.io/blog/conan-package-manager-pilot-to-end-in-december

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I should have read the message correctly on page
https://wiki.qt.io/Using_Conan_for_Qt6#Connecting_to_Conan_remote

Actually, conan still attempts to log in to Qt, but Qt refuses it.